# NSURL end with %20

Tags: objective-c, nsurl

It bothers me a bit to ask you for help on a problem like this but I really need help...

I don't understand why but my `NSURL` ends with %20.

***My code:***

```
 NSString *imagestring = [NSString stringWithString:images];
        NSLog(@"String image : %@" , imagestring);
        NSURL *urlimage = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[imagestring stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
        NSLog(@"Url image:  %@" , urlimage);
```

***Console output:***

```
2014-05-02 20:52:03.453 Xbox One Sortie[1438:70b] String image : http://media.melty.fr/article-1488731-ajust_930/call-of-duty-ghosts.jpg 
2014-05-02 20:52:03.454 Xbox One Sortie[1438:70b] Url image:  http://media.melty.fr/article-1488731-ajust_930/call-of-duty-ghosts.jpg%20
```

Comment: If you really want to check white space check with `NSLog(@"String image : ==%@==" , imagestring);` add `==` at start and end of url..

Comment: effectively i can see a space before == . thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%20` is nothing but **white space**.

Because of `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding` you see space as `%20`.

If you have whitespace at the end, use below code to remove it.

```
NSString *string = @" this text has spaces before and after ";
NSString *trimmedString = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                              [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
```